# Meaning of なんか面白いことが起こりそうな予感

Tags: grammar, meaning

> これって、古い文字で書いてあるみたいだけど、読める？
>
> うん、古文は得意だから
>
> えーと、「世界、闇に覆われし時、天女に導かれたる超魔神現れん」
>
> ――だって
>
> うーん、よく分からないけど、なんか面白いことが起こりそうな予感

Looking at the above excerpt, I'm not sure whether I'm overthinking things or whether it doesn't mean what I think it does. On first glance I thought it might be just a shortened way of saying 予感がする but I'm not quite sure if this is right. Take for example, 今日も暑くなりそうな予感がする朝, which talks about a morning which gives that impression(as opposed to saying that is the premonition someone has). So my question is, does the statement mean that they have the above mentioned premonition, the message gives that impression, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common technique named 「体言止{たいげんど}め」, which is to end a sentence with a noun or pronoun instead of a verb or adjective, which is more "normal" for the language.

「体言」 means "nouns and pronouns" and 「止め」, "ending (a sentence)".

This technique allows the reader/listener to finish up the sentence.  So, it is all up to you.  Most native speakers, however, would read the sentence as being:

> 「なんか面白{おもしろ}いことが起{お}こりそうな予感{よかん}**がする**。」

or

> 「なんか面白いことが起こりそうな予感**がある**。」

In your words, it is "they have the above mentioned premonition".